# assembly does not match manifest

Tags: c#, manifest, system.reactive

I have project that is useing Reactiveui (v 7.0) and Simple injector. Reactiveui uses System.Reactive.Linq v2.2.5.0.  In my project (which uses .net 4.5.1), I'm referencing System.Reacive v3.0.0. I added the following to App.config to handle the redirection:

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Reactive.Linq" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

But when I run it, I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reactive.Linq, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.

I have also tried System.Reactive v3.1 but it gives the same error.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the dll is signed with that key? you can check using the sn.exe tool from a visual studio command prompt.

Comment: yes, that is the key for v2.2.5.0. If I change the key it complains (correctly) that v2.2.5.0 doesn't match the manifest. I've also tried deleting all files from the bin\debug folder and still get the error.

Comment: You were right, it was a key error. I noticed in another thread that the public keys must match or it can't redirect.  So I got the error to go away by removing the redirects and also referencing the rx-main nuget pkg instead of system.reactive.core directly.

Comment: Thank you very much